# How to check in jenkins groovy pipelines if a specific artifact filename was collected?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to know how can I check if a file was previously collected as an artifact during a Jenkins groovy pipeline execution?

```
...
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'foo.txt', allowEmptyArchive: true
...
// if 'foo.txt' in artifacts: do something
```

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044543/what-exactly-does-archive-artifacts-step-do-in-jenkins you should scan `%JENKINS_HOME%/jobs/MY_JOB/builds/...` for your file of interest